# Convert nested <ul><li> to PHP nested array

Tags: php, html

I want to convert nested `ul` `li` to a PHP array.

The HTML code that I have is something looks like:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li id="firstNavItem"><a href="index.html">Home</li>
    <li><a href="Warp.html">Warp</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Warp-how-it-works.html">How it works</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Warp-Engine.html">Warp Engine</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="WarpFactors.html">Warp Factors</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Fuel</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Anti-Matter.html">Anti-Matter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Deuterium.html">Deuterium</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Fact-or-Fiction.html">Fact or Fiction</li>
    <li><a href="StarTrek.html">Star Trek</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Enterprise.html">Enterprise</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Voyager.html">Voyager</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li> </ul>
```

It must be converted to an array.

I tried several ways to parse, But I fail.

One of the ways that I've used is:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$i = 0;

while( is_object($finance = $doc->getElementsByTagName("li")->item($i)) )
{
    foreach($finance->childNodes as $nodename)
    {
        if($nodename->nodeName == 'li')
        {
            foreach($nodename->childNodes as $subNodes)
            {
                $arr[$i] = $subNodes->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $s = explode('             ', $nodename->nodeValue);
            if (count($s) == 1)
            {
                $arr[$i] =$nodename->nodeValue;
            }
            else
            {
                $arr[$i] =  $s;
            }

        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a recursive procedure. Find the top-most `<ul>` and create an array for that. Then find the `<li>` children and make them elements of the array. Then if the element contains another `<ul>`, create a sub-array there and recurse.

Comment: How are you getting on with this? Have you tried out my example? Please let me know if you need any more guidance.

Comment: This does not work. This beginning of ths final structure with this code is: 
Array
(
    [0] => Home
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => How it works
            
            Warp Engine
            
            Warp Factors
            
            Fuel

            [1] =>    Anti-Matter

            [2] =>        

            [3] =>        Deuterium

            [4] =>        

            [5] =>    
        
        )......

Comment: Have worked out a solution? My updated code should be working now.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if you got this working?

Answer (score 4):

The following code gives a nested array. I don't think it's clear exactly what the outputted array should look like, but this code gives the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => Home
            [items] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => Warp
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => How it works
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => Warp Engine
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => Warp Factors
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => Fuel
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [key] => Anti-Matter
                                            [items] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [key] => Deuterium
                                            [items] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => Fact or Fiction
            [items] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key] => Star Trek
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => Enterprise
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => Voyager
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [key] => About
            [items] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Code:

```
<?php

class Parser {

    private $elements = [];

    public function parse() {
        $doc = new \DOMDocument();
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $doc->loadHTMLFile("./html.html");

        $this->parseChildNodes($doc, $this->elements);
    }

    private function parseChildNodes($node, & $arrayToPush) {
        $indexPushed = count($arrayToPush);

        if ($node->nodeName == "li") {
            $representation = [
                "key" => $this->getDisplayValueFromNode($node),
                "items" => []
            ];
            array_push($arrayToPush, $representation);
            $arrayToPush = & $arrayToPush[$indexPushed]["items"];
        }

        if ($node->childNodes == null) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
            $this->parseChildNodes($child, $arrayToPush);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the node's first element
     * In our case this is the text value of the anchor tag
     *
     * @param $node
     * @return String
     */
    private function getDisplayValueFromNode($node) {
        return $node->firstChild->nodeValue;
    }

    public function getElements() {
        return $this->elements;
    }
}

$parser = new Parser();
$parser->parse();
print_r($parser->getElements());
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not easy, but I wasn't aware that you could access the DOM with PHP, so it was an interesting challenge.

This will work for nested lists up to two deep, you could refactor this to make it easier to handle deeper lists.

The below code should help you to get your lists into arrays. I have left echo statements in for ease of demonstration.

```
<?php
    $data = <<<EOT
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li id="firstNavItem"><a href="index.html">Home</li>
    <li><a href="Warp.html">Warp</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Warp-how-it-works.html">How it works</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Warp-Engine.html">Warp Engine</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="WarpFactors.html">Warp Factors</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Fuel</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Anti-Matter.html">Anti-Matter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Deuterium.html">Deuterium</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Fact-or-Fiction.html">Fact or Fiction</li>
    <li><a href="StarTrek.html">Star Trek</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Enterprise.html">Enterprise</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Voyager.html">Voyager</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
EOT;

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadHTML($data);

    $list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);
    foreach ($list->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeName == 'li'
            &&
            $node->lastChild->nodeName != 'ul'
        ) {
            echo $node->textContent . "<br>";
        } else {
            if ($node->lastChild->childNodes) {
                foreach ($node->lastChild->childNodes as $node2) {
                    if ($node2->nodeName == 'li'
                        &&
                        $node2->lastChild->nodeName != 'ul'
                    ) {
                        echo "&bull; " . $node2->textContent . "<br>";
                    } else {
                        if ($node2->lastChild->childNodes) {
                            foreach ($node2->lastChild->childNodes as $node3) {
                                if ($node3->nodeName == 'li'
                                    &&
                                    $node3->lastChild->nodeName != 'ul'
                                ) {
                                    echo "&bull; &bull; " . $node3->textContent . "<br>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're right, I must not have had error reporting turned on.

Comment: I think I've got a problem with the amount of times the array loops.

Comment: You should be able to see that is sort of works, in between the errors the structure is correct. I'm at work at the moment so I can't help any more than that currently. Please let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns all nodes with that name (including nested ones), so there is no need to additionally search through the child nodes. The code in the snippet below returns this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Home
    [1] => Warp
    [2] => How it works
    [3] => Warp Engine
    [4] => Warp Factors
    [5] => Fuel
    [6] => Anti-Matter
    [7] => Deuterium
    [8] => Fact or Fiction
    [9] => Star Trek
    [10] => Enterprise
    [11] => Voyager
    [12] => About
)
```

Code:

```
<?php

class Parser {

    private $elements = [];

    public function parse() {
        $doc = new \DOMDocument();
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $doc->loadHTMLFile("./html.html");

        foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName("li") as $node) {
            array_push($this->elements, $node->firstChild->nodeValue);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the node's first element
     * In our case this is the text value of the anchor tag
     *
     * @param $node
     * @return String
     */
    private function getDisplayValueFromNode($node) {
        return $node->firstChild->nodeValue;
    }

    public function getElements() {
        return $this->elements;
    }
}

$parser = new Parser();
$parser->parse();
print_r($parser->getElements());
```

Comment: The array need to be nested, like the list.

Comment: At least, I think it does :/

Comment: The array needs to be nested.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what the final array should look like? How should the nested items by keyed?

Comment: @user3834658 it just converts a nested ul > li list to a nested array, just it. :-)

Comment: @ahmed Could you please try and draw out the structure? A simple nested array would look like: [Home, [How it works, Warp Engine, [Anti-Matter, Deuterium]], but you then loose the keys of the list: Warp and Fuel. I don't think that you cannot nest simple arrays when they need to both be in order (of the html) and by keyed by their parent li. Please take a look at my second answer, which contains the parent li elements, but where each array element is a map.